# How to speed up search on MYSQL FullText or change the query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I use fulltext in MySQL I need to select two fields in two different tables
And also the search priority with the name field in the first table. That's why I multiplied the result in 2 by sorting. And this is a good quirky show. But there is a problem with too much time, and in some cases about 30 seconds. What changes should I make to increase the speed of this query?

**note:**

> ft_stopword_file = ""
>
> ft_min_word_len=1
>
> The record count of each table is 200,000

**query:**

```
$search="hello* my* name* in* prim* this* in* a* test*"

SELECT f.id, f.name FROM
Find f left join Movie m on f.`tID`=m.`id`
WHERE MATCH(f.`name`,m.`text`) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH(f.`name`,m.`text`) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +
(MATCH(f.`name`) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) *2) DESC , length(f.Address)
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move 2 `MATCH`-es our of `ORDER BY` as well as out of `WHERE` into main `SELECT` field list to be re-used later:

```
$search="hello* my* name* in* prim* this* in* a* test*"

SELECT 
   f.id, f.name,
   MATCH(f.`name`,m.`text`) AGAINST('$search') as relevance1,
   (MATCH(f.`name`) AGAINST('$search') *2) as relevance2
FROM
Find f left join Movie m on f.`tID`=m.`id`
WHERE MATCH(f.`name`,m.`text`) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relevance1 + relevance2 DESC , length(f.Address)
LIMIT 30
```

The above code chuck is **just the idea**, I can't verify it runs without errors because I don't have your schema+data. So just play with it and see if you can make it work. Then compare execution plans from your original code and this one. I think there should be performance increase.

Also, you should not be using `IN BOOLEAN MODE` for relevance used in `ORDER BY`
if you want to get real relevance data. `IN BOOLEAN MODE` will always return relevance of 1.0 if there is a match. But in `WHERE` I would use match in `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

HTH

PS. Another idea is to calculate match by `f.name` and `m.text` separately and then build up proper `relevance1` and `relevance2` variables and use them in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thanks for reply but this query has error "Unknown column 'relevance1' in 'where clause'"

Comment: yes, means you can't reference MATCH from select list in WHERE. So you have to call full MATCH in where but see if you at least can re-use relevance1 and relevance2 in ORDERY BY.